# Change form field value in django, after __init__ but before cleaning

Tags: python, django

I want to reset the value of some fields in my django form to `None`, inside the `__init__` method of my form.

This is what I have so far:

```
class MyFormForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = ['field1', ...]

    field1 = forms.IntegerField(max_value=100)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        values_changed = kwargs.pop('values_changed', False)
        super(MyFormForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.data = self.data.copy()

        if not values_changed:
            for field in self.fields:
                self.data[field] = None
```

Unfortunately, when the form is displayed in my template, the value that has been POSTed is still in it. How do I get rid of the value, so that the change takes effect in the template, which renders the form?

Things that don't work:

- Setting the initial parameter. Since there is a value present, it will be ignored
- Using cleaned values. The form is not cleaned at this stage, since it is not valid. Because of this `cleaned_data` does not exist

I'm accessing the values like this:

```
{{ form.field1.value|default_if_none:"Please enter." }}
```

*edit:* I just tried

```
{{ form.data.field1|default_if_none:"Please enter." }}
```

no change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm a moron. There were two forms, `form` and `form_2`.

I used the wrong variable name. My bad. It works like it should with the code above.